# Knitr - Centre align and separate a table of tables

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown, kable

I'm using rmarkdown and I need to build a table of 2 tables so that

- the table containing the 2 tables is itself centre-aligned, and
- the two tables sit a few cm's apart so that they're more readable.

Below, I've included two tables and some some markdown that almost gets there but any help would be appreciated. **The the last line of HTML (right at the bottom of the snippet) is, I think, where I need the help.**

#### Data and a stab at the problem

````
---
title: "A tale of two tables"
output: html_document
---
```{r global_options, R.options=knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)}
```

```{r two-tables, results='asis'}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

a <- tribble(~location, ~'Month (persons)', ~'TTY (persons)', ~'TTY % change',
       'new_south_wales',1604,40328,3.3,
       'victoria',-2118,13415,3.5,
       'queensland',214,10023,3.2,
       'south_australia',1969,11787,5.0,
       'western_australia',531,1316,1.6,
       'tasmania',-887,2428,1.9,
       'northern_territory',-44,570,2.4,
       'australian_capital_territory',32,-434,-3.1,
       'australia',78,1060,4.8)

b <- tribble(~series,~Dec,~Jan,~TTY,
       'FT employed', 12700, 49800, 293200,
       'PT employed', 20700, 65900, 110100,
       'Total', 33500, 16000, 403300,
       'per cent', 0.3, 0.1, 3.3,
       'Agg hours worked', -0.8, -1.5, 0.5,
       'Part rate', 65.7, 65.6, 64.6,
       'Ue', 5.56, 5.49, 5.7)

### Creating the tables
## Federal employment table
test_federal <- kable(b, format = "html", output = F) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", 'hover', 'condensed', 'responsive'), full_width = F, position = 'left', font_size = 11) %>%
  add_indent(4) %>% 
  row_spec(row = 3, bold = TRUE) %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" ", 'Month (sa)' = 2, 'Year (sa)' = 1))

## State employment table
test_state <- a %>% 
  mutate(
    'TTY % change' = color_bar('lightblue')(.$`TTY % change`)
  ) %>% 
  kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE, output = F) %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", 'hover', 'condensed', 'responsive'), full_width = F, position = 'right', font_size = 11) %>% 
  row_spec(row = 9, bold = TRUE) %>% 
  add_header_above(c("", "Dec" = 1, "Dec" = 1, "Dec" = 1))

cat(c('<table><tr valign="top"><td>', test_federal, '</td>', '<td>', test_state, '</td></tr></table>'), sep = '')
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center a table, you can set the `table` `margin` to `auto`.

To separate both tables, I see two solutions.

#### Use a cell padding

I think this is the most obvious solution. You can apply a [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) to your cells. For instance:

```
cat(
  c('<table style="margin: auto"><tr valign="top"><td style="padding-right: 2cm">', 
    test_federal, 
    '</td>', 
    '<td>', 
    test_state, 
    '</td></tr></table>'
  ), 
  sep = ''
)
```

#### Use a border spacing

You can use the [`border-spacing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) for `<table>` elements.
In order to use `border-spacing`, you have to set `border-collapse` property to `separate`.

Replace the last line with:

```
cat(
  c('<table style="margin: auto; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 2cm"><tr valign="top"><td>', 
    test_federal, 
    '</td>', 
    '<td>', 
    test_state, 
    '</td></tr></table>'
  ), 
  sep = ''
)
```

The difference with the first solution is that you get a space before the first cell and after the last cell. You can see the difference with removing `margin: auto`.